# Continuous function on the unit interval with commuting compositions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Let $I$ be the unit interval and $f, g:I\to I$ be continuous functions. Assume that $f\circ g = g\circ f$.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791535/f-circ-g-g-circ-f-increasing-rightarrow-common-fixed-point) post shows that if $f$ and $g$ in addition are assumed to be increasing then $f$ and $g$ have a common fixed point.

> **Question.** Does the same conclusion hold without assuming that $f$ and $g$ are monotonically increasing?

I couldn't construct any examples where the same conclusion does not hold.

**Some Observations.**

1. If $\text{Fix}(f) = \{x\in I: f(x) = x\}$ and $\text{Fix}(g) = \{x\in I:\ g(x) = x\}$, then $\text{Fix}(g)$ is $f$-invariant and $\text{Fix}(f)$ is $g$-invariant.
2. The set $\{x\in I:\ f(x) = g(x)\}$ (which, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003056/for-continuous-f-g-0-1-to-0-1-with-f-circ-g-g-circ-f-there-exist?rq=1), is not empty) is both $f$ and $g$-invariant.

Comment: A really interesting question. Many researchers have studied such questions but, as far as I can remember, they always assumed homeomorphisms of the unit interval. In the 2nd question that you [linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003056/for-continuous-f-g-0-1-to-0-1-with-f-circ-g-g-circ-f-there-exist?rq=1) they don't mention monotonicity. Or am I missing anything?

Comment: This is a hard question which was open for a long time. The answer is "no":  Boyce, W.M.: Commuting functions with no common fixed point. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.
137, 77-92 (1969).

Comment: @KurtG. Yes one does not require monotonocity for the second observation.

Comment: Very interesting !  Would like to point out that for monotone functions that commute there are a number of interesting results. For example M.K. Fort, showed in *The embedding of homeomorphisms in flows* Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.,
6, 960–967, (1955) that there is a one paramter semigroup of homeomorphisms which $f$ and $g$ belong to. This is also related to a functional equation that goes back to Niels Hendrik Abel.

Comment: @Gerd Thank you so much for the reference.